# How to make a php template engine?

Tags: php, html, arrays, templates

I need to make a small and simple php template engine I searched a lot and many of them were too complex to understand and I don't want to use smarty and other similar engines, I have got some idea from Stack Overflow like this:

```
$template = file_get_contents('file.html');
$array = array('var1' => 'value',
                'txt' => 'text');

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  $template = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $template);
}

echo $template;
```

Now instead of echo the template I just want to add include "file.html" and it will display the file with correct variable values and I want to put the engine in a separate place and just include it in the template what I want to use it declare the array and at the end include the html file like phpbb. Sorry I am asking to much but can anyone just explain the basic concept behind this?

EDIT: Well let me be frank i am making a forum script and i have got tons of ideas for it but i want make its template system like phpbb so i need a separate template engine custom one if you can help then please you are invited to work with me. sorry for the ad.. :p

Comment: Why don't you want to use Smarty? What advantages will your approach have over other templating engines?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? If its just a case you don't want to invest the time in learning smarty then I think you are making a mistake. It will save you time in the long run as the smarty developers have already solved all the problems that you will encounter trying to create your own engine.

Comment: PHP already is a template engine. Smarty IS reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "PHP already is a template engine." In the very strictest sense, this is true, but there are certain times where it is extremely verbose and inflexible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What if, for a script easier to maintain, you move those to functions?

something like this:

```
<?php

function get_content($file, $data)
{
   $template = file_get_contents($file);

   foreach($data as $key => $value)
   {
     $template = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $template);
   }

   return $template;
}
```

And you can use it this way:

```
<?php

$file = '/path/to/your/file.php';
$data = = array('var1' => 'value',
                'txt' => 'text');

echo get_content($file, $data);
```

Answer (score 13):

file.html:

```
<html>

<body>
<h3>Hi there, <?php echo $name ?></h3>
</body>

</html>
```

file.php:

```
<?php
    $name = "Keshav";
    include('file.html');
?>
```

Doesn't get simpler than this. Yes, it uses global variables, but if simple is the name of the game, this is it. Simply visit 'http://example.com/file.php' and off you go.

Now, if you want the user to see 'file.html' in the browser's address bar, you'd have to configure your webserver to treat .html files as PHP scripts, which is a little more complicated, but definitely doable. Once that's done, you can combine both files into a single one:

file.html:

```
<?php
    $name = "Keshav";
?>
<html>

<body>
<h3>Hi there, <?php echo $name ?></h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would give +100 if I could, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. PHP means PHP Hypertext Processor, and "Hypertext" is not there by mistake...

Comment: Would you like a template engine to make your templates templatable?

Comment: A hundred times yes. **PHP is a template engine**. Enable short tags and it's not a half bad template engine at that.

Comment: I know but i just wanted to keep things separate php part for the php developers and html part for the html developers and easy to change themes when needed

Answer (score 3):

Once you iron out all bugs, fix huge performance problem you're getting yourself into, you'll end up with template engine just like Smarty and otheres.

Such find'n'replace approach is much slower than compilation to PHP. It does not handle escaping very well (you'll run into XSS problems). It will be quite difficult to add conditions and loops, and you will need them sooner or later.

Comment: true but once you put the effort into building your own code you get several important benefits: you learned how it works (probably the most important); you can fix bugs yourself; it's usually very lightweight with only the stuff you need; you don't have a dependency (and security issues) of 3rd party packages

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php
    class view {
        private $file;
        private $vars = array();

        public function __construct($file) {
            $this->file = $file;
        }

        public function __set($key, $val) {
            $this->vars[$key] = $val;
        }

        public function __get($key, $val) {
            return (isset($this->vars[$key])) ? $this->vars[$key] : null;
        }

        public function render() {
            //start output buffering (so we can return the content)
            ob_start();
            //bring all variables into "local" variables using "variable variable names"
            foreach($this->vars as $k => $v) {
                $$k = $v;
            }

            //include view
            include($this->file);

            $str = ob_get_contents();//get teh entire view.
            ob_end_clean();//stop output buffering
            return $str;
        }
    }
```

Here's how to use it:

```
    <?php
    $view = new view('userprofile.php');
    $view->name = 'Afflicto';
    $view->bio = "I'm a geek.";
    echo $view->render();
```

Comment: You need to give credit where it belongs!!
http://www.sitepoint.com/flexible-view-manipulation-1/

Comment: a -1 because of oop where it's not needed at all. +1 for the buffer use. so a 0 from me.